# Cloud of career-related tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [[work], [job], [career-development], [employment] => [career]](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163/work-job-career-development-employment-career)

We have four tags containing the word "career": career, career-development, career-advice, and career-guidance. I propose a tag merge to "career". Upvote to agree, answer with your point of contention if you disagree.