# Tag merge discussion: jobs → career

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

In the first part of what will assuredly be a several part series on [tag cleanups](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/yet-another-cleanup-idea), I'd like to discuss merging [jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs) into [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career).

Both tags generally are about jobs: working at a job, career development, getting a job, etc.

Is there a reason we need to keep these tags separate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [seems to have been proposed a long time ago](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/163/3249) but never followed through on.  This is what happens when you let them fester...

Anyway, to me there are actually several different subcategories of career questions, almost none of which are properly represented by the current tags:

- **Career development** means advancing one's career, irrespective of their current job.  In other words, topics such as becoming a more attractive/in-demand employee or candidate, advancing up the ranks, or developing interviewing or negotiating skills.  Some well-defined CD questions are:

  - [How to market yourself as a software developer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/54506/3249)
  - [Which skills would you expect and appreciate in a Junior Software Engineer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/48100/3249)
  - [Do I need to go to a big-name university?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/35208/3249)
  - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/13892/3249
- **Career advice** is essentially an umbrella term for aimless "help me, I fail at life" questions which should be terminated with extreme prejudice.  Right now, these tend to share the [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) tag.

  - [I'm graduating with a Computer Science degree but I don't feel like I know how to program](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/43528/3249) (thanks Stack Overflow!)
  - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/18502/3249
  - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/29213/3249
  - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/21782/3249
- Then there are **job rants**, which I personally don't even think deserve the dignity of being closed (as opposed to flat-out deleted).  The hallmark of these topics is that the essential question - if there actually is one - is almost always some variant of *"should I quit?"*:

  - [What stressors do programmers encounter on the job, and how do you deal with them?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/74913/3249)
  - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/20866/3249
  - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/22609/3249
- Several questions exist about **finding and acquiring jobs**.  These are similar, on the surface, to career development questions, but tend to be at the tactical rather than strategic level:

  - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/13811/3249
  - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/14551/3249
  - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/37915/3249
- There are also some (admittedly few) from the **employer** or **management** side, many of which are legitimately tagged [project-management](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) and don't deserve to be saddled with [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career):

  - [Should companies consider remote employees or stick to local employees?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/348/3249)
  - [Leading a  not-so-good team](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/50616/3249)
  - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/46920/3249
  - [Dealing with engineers that frequently leave their jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/43409/3249)
- Finally there are several - far too many, actually, including a *ridiculous* number of "talking to management" questions - that I would classify as **managing one's own job**:

  - [How is leaving on time perceived in software companies?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/70765/3249)
  - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/59740/3249
  - [Does keeping a journal help in your job?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/3383/3249)
  - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/34570/3249

To me, this is not just a simple matter of merging a tag.  The [jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs) tag itself is very unfocused and contains a lot of questions about job searching, job management, and I think a few about hiring.  Merging it with the [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) tag will only create more chaos in *that* tag.

I'd like to suggest dispensing entirely with both the [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) and [jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs) tags and propose the following new categories (of course, this is just a suggestion):

- [career-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development) for questions that are about... uh, career development. This is currently a synonym of [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) - it probably shouldn't be.
- [job-searching](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-searching) or [job-market](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-market) for questions about getting a [new] job.  I'd suggest [employment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment) instead, but I think that is prone to misinterpretation.
- [job-satisfaction](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-satisfaction) for questions about work/life balance, creating better workspaces, etc.
- [job-advancement](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-advancement) and also [teamwork](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teamwork) for questions about excelling in one's current position. [job-performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-performance) might be another possibility.
- [project-management](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) and/or [employee-relations](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employee-relations) and/or [business](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business) for employer-focused questions.

This is the type of thing that's only going to be solved by a long, arduous process of community-supported hand-sorting.  Fortunately, I think this site has enough daily activity to support some bulk manual retagging.

Alternatively, go ahead and merge it all into [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) but then put the [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) tag on notice saying that it needs to be phased out and sorted into subcategories.

Comment: A positive side-effect of having well-focused tags is that they tend to result in more focused questions.  With a broad [career] tag it seems like anything goes - hence the awful "advice" questions - however, with the proposed list above, it's hard to find a tag in which to fit the rambling nonsense. Of course some people will try anyway, but this is a game of inches.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but historically, tag choice is not given this much consideration, and everything gets tagged randomly (or worse, simultaneously) with all career-related tags. If I'm looking info on getting a job, that's career advice, isn't it? Learning a language? Career advice! Am I doing a good job? Career advice. Developing my career? Well I'm asking for advice about my career, so... you get the picture. I'd rather see one general tag being used for these questions than a ton of tags being misused because nobody wants to think about tagging: they just want to ask a question.

Comment: @Mark: That "one tag" is an ambiguous, unclear tag which accounts for nearly 10% of all questions on the site. Your comment suggests that the current use of [career] is not already a misuse; I'd argue that it is, because it was originally intended to be for career *development* questions, but because of its vagueness, started to be applied to all sorts of other questions. I'd rather see 5 or 6 smaller (but still large) tags get misused than one inscrutable mega-tag, because the misuse is more obvious in the former case and people will retag. If the tags make no sense, nobody bothers.

Comment: @Mark: Keep in mind that there is tag auto-complete; I seriously doubt that people will get confused to the point of brain-implosion if there is only one "career" tag and maybe 4 or 5 "job" tags. It's not like we're asking people to sift through dozens of tags to find the one they're looking for. If somebody is so lazy that they can't choose from a list of 4 or 5, then they probably put about the same level of effort into the question itself (i.e. none).

Comment: I meant to say that [career-development], [career-advice], [career], [jobs], and all the related tags are currently subject to [excessive misuse](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=career-development), which is why they were merged or being considered for merge: nobody was parsing career advice questions that finely, and the existence of tags led to confusion we indiscriminately welcomed *all* career-development questions. Career/job-development/advice is only on-topic under a very specific set of criteria, and many of the questions out there now should probably just be closed.

Comment: To that end, I think I'd favor your alternative: sort the whole pile into one tag, get your posse on it (which, by the way, is going quite strong, I might add!), and sort out the survivors later.

Comment: @Mark: Perhaps the tag [career-development] needs more refinement, as that seems to have been the one that got people into a tizzy; I *don't* think that merging it all into [career] was the right answer, because that just makes it looks like any career questions *at all* are allowed. I guess as long as people are diligent about retagging, it'll work either way...

Comment: In addition to the tag auto-complete, there is also a pre-submit-question script which can apply some rule-based blocking on misuse of tags. This is the orange popup that says "Oops... something" the moment you hit "Post Question". By putting those ad-hoc rules in the submit trigger, it does not affect the realtime performance of the auto-complete. The pre-submit trigger can also automatically flag for moderator notice.

Answer (score 2):

No reason I know of. Lots of closed questions in both. I would support merging them.

Answer (score 0):

I would support eliminating both tags since very few seem to not get closed.