# Blacklist [career-advice]

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, tags, tag-blacklist

This tag is a broken window, and it's causing problems by its continued existence:

- People [see the tag and assume career advice questions are automatically on-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102177/ever-wondered-why-i-havent-got-that-job-position-instead-of-him-her)
- It's a Venus Fly Trap for Bad questions
- It's a completely superfluous tag to our *other* bad career tag, [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career)

We've [already discussed how bad this tag is](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/tag-merge-discussion-jobs-career/1952#1952), and should it go away, none of the questions still tagged with it would be untagged.

Can [career-advice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-advice) please be blacklisted once and for all?

Comment: Why does this need a blacklist? Why can't you just synonymize it with [career]?

Comment: @Mr.CRT [tag:career] is next on the list (see [linked discussion](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/tag-merge-discussion-jobs-career/1952#1952)), but requires a large tag cleanup effort. Forwarding people to use career instead of career advice just pushes back the problem for no benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have six questions in that tag, all closed - you could just delete them and the tag would go away... [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) looks like the bigger monster here, but you obviously have your work cut out for you before *that* can be removed easily.

If people are re-creating the tag for bad questions, then you have bad questions to close. If they're re-creating it for *good* questions, then it should be synonymized with something else. Blacklisting it seems like sweeping the problem under the rug - the problem being the questions themselves...

Comment: The rest of the career-advice questions have been deleted: hopefully the tag doesn't pop back up again.

Comment: Deleting the questions that are using the tag doesn't stop any user to tag another question with that tag; if the tag is black-listed, nobody could use it anymore.

Comment: By and large, blacklists are for bad *tags*... Not bad questions. @kia

Comment: I know, but deleting the questions using that tag doesn't stop users from asking another question with that tag. If the tag is bad, then it should black-listed; if the tag is good, but used on questions that should not use it, or bad questions, then that is not the fault of the tag. I didn't mean the tag should be blocked because it is not used correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The linked post has the tags [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career), [jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs), [job-market](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-market). and [career-advice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-advice).  Except for [job-market](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-market), they could all be synonyms.

However, there are other tags with a similar problem.  Here are the tag wiki excerpt and body for each tag:

- [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career)
  **Excerpt**: Questions about career, rather than a specific programming project.
  **Wiki**: See the separate tags for hiring and interviewing.
- [jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs)
  **Excerpt**: The [jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs) tag has no wiki summary, would you like to [help us create it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1279)
  **Wiki**: No wiki
- [career-advice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-advice)
  **Excerpt**: This tag is no longer used. Please see tag wiki for better alternatives.
  **Wiki**:

  > This tag is no longer used, as general career advice questions are not on-topic here. Please use the following suggestions instead:
  >
  > - [career-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development) for questions that are about developing your career.
  > - [job-searching](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-searching) or [job-market](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-market) for questions about getting a *new* job.
  > - [job-satisfaction](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-satisfaction) for questions about work/life balance, creating better workspaces, etc.
  > - [job-advancement](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-advancement) and also [teamwork](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teamwork) for questions about excelling in one's current position.
  > - [project-management](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) and/or [employee-relations](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employee-relations) and/or [business](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business) for employer-focused questions.
- [job-market](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-market)
  **Excerpt**: Career prospects as programmers in general. Likelihood of getting hired if one is seeking a new position,a.k.a. job. There can be some cases where the question is rather specific in terms of applying to a small geographic area however.
  **Wiki**: Same as Excerpt.

With the exception of [job-market](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-market), none of these tags mention that they should be exclusive to programming.  For honeypot tags like this, it's important that the excerpt mentions that they must be applied to programming-specific problems.  [career-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development) is colloquially synonymous with [career-advice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-advice), but *it has no excerpt*.  By blacklisting one pair of words, you're just killing the messenger.

Fix the excerpts, so that users see something useful when they type the tags in.

Comment: The journey of a thousand miles begins with one step. Career-advice sucks *today* and is being used as a justification for asking general career advice questions *today*. We need to start somewhere with cleaning up the tags, banning career-advice is a big first step.

Comment: The career-advice tag [excerpt was changed because what was there was awful](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/100097/revisions). The career-development tag was also reintroduced today as part of the implementation of [this discussion](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/tag-merge-discussion-jobs-career/1952#1952).

Comment: Whoops, should have looked at the revision history.  Still, I suggest you include "as applies to programming" in the excerpt of potentially bad tags.

Comment: I've fixed the wikis for [tag:career-advice] and [tag:job-market] and added a wiki for [tag:career-development] and [tag:jobs]. But I don't think we need to address all the problems with related tags before getting rid of the obviously bad ones.