# Migrating tag wikis from SO

Tags: discussion, tag-wikis

I've just added a tag wiki for [myslq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/mysql/info), essentially copying the text from SO's [mysql tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info), leaving out the popular questions section as they are SO questions as felt that we should do something similar with PSE questions, *but didn't bother to actually do it*.

I'm wondering if it would be of any value to automate the process (*ask our overlords to do it for us*) and just link tag wikis across SE, or at least between SO and PSE, in which same tags will most probably refer to the same subject. We have a few empty tag wikis for popular (or somewhat popular) tags, i.e. [oracle](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/oracle/info), that have great and peer reviewed info on their SO wikis.

And if we can't automate it, would it be generally acceptable to just copy paste the info from SO? That would give the copy paster 4 points (2 for excerpt and 2 for body) and that somehow feels wrong. (*although I'm expecting my 4 points for my hard work at the mysql tag wiki soon, people*)

---

**edit**

I got my 4 points (and a badge) for the mysql tag. And I'm now fighting the urge to copy paste info on all our empty tag wikis...

Comment: I thought this too - but in the cases where I did copy, either the wiki information was fairly basic or I had to edit the body of the wiki anyway to remove links to specific questions and other site specific information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't!

Tag wikis are meant to provide context and guidance for how the tag is supposed to be used on the site: how they relate to other tags, what types of questions work, links to frequently asked questions, etc. Generalized tag wikis don't really help anything or teach people how we want our site to be organized.

This is the reason why there are strict requirements to be able to edit a tag wiki without approval: someone on the site intimately familiar with the tag is going to know what works and what doesn't.

I approved it because it looked good on its own merits within the context of Programmers. There are going to be *some* tag wikis that could work just as well here as well as Stack Overflow, but there are going to be just as many that won't.

Because there's not going to be a hard and fast rule on what's going to work and what isn't, I'd hold off on suggesting wikis *en masse*: we've had a long-standing problem with thoughtless tagging and we're just starting to clean that up.

Instead, if you can focus on suggesting tag wikis that provide information in the context of Programmers, that'd be preferable. One section of tags we could really use some help with are the career/jobs tags. Kevin Vermeer [pointed out a few tags that could use some love](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2146/blacklist-career-advice/2148#2148). Aaronaught had [some thoughts](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/tag-merge-discussion-jobs-career/1952#1952) about that, too.

Comment: Rethinking the question, I see that the "some tag wikis that could work just as well here as well as Stack Overflow" are not that many after all... And I did do some minor editing on the mysql wiki (removing the so questions).