# Is it kosher to copy a tag wiki from another SE site?

Tags: discussion

I see that the [[VBA] tag doesn't yet have a tag wiki on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/vba/info), whereas [the one on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/info) is well established.  Since the tag is exactly the same, would it be acceptable to simply copy that tag wiki over (removing SO cross-references of course) or is this taboo?

---

[**Related**: this answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2456/131580), though this doesn't appear to preclude the idea that *some* SO tag wikis might provide appropriate content for Programmers tag wikis.

I would still be curious to know if it would be acceptable for me to port over the specific tag in my question, [VBA].  Comments?

Comment: with appropriate attribution, this may be okay: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/310

Answer (score 2):

Should the tag wiki be the same though?

The focus of the sites is different and we don't need to go into the technical details that are present in the Stack Overflow tag. Our tag should be more of an overview/history perhaps with a link to the Stack Overflow tag wiki for more information.