# Career Advice type questions

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-blacklist

Perhaps a duplicate of [Blacklist [career-advice]](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2146/blacklist-career-advice) (status deferred)

The FAQs state (*inter alia*):

> and it is not about...
>
> - general workplace issues, office politics, résumé help,
> - career advice, salary or compensation1

However, we still get questions, and we maintain tags [career-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development), [job-market](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-market), [job-searching](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-searching), [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) etc

Yes, we can keep flagging them, but can these tags be consigned to the blackhole?

Comment: Why [tag:career-advice] is status deferred is discussed [here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2358/offering-solutions-to-the-career-and-jobs-tags).

Comment: Our long, national nightmare concerning [tag:career] was resolved [last March](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3279/blacklist-career) and it's been empty since. The others are loose ends, though.

Comment: As an aside, I have been meaning to resurrect tag clean-ups in some form and see if there's interest. But I've just been insane busy.

Comment: Thanks Thomas...