# Posse request: jobs/career/etc. tag cleanup

Tags: discussion, moderation, tags, posse

We [discussed](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/tag-merge-discussion-jobs-career) merging [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) and [jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs), but now it's time to put a plan into action. [Aaronut's plan](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/tag-merge-discussion-jobs-career/1952#1952) is great, but we need some help from the *posse*:

#### Step 1: Clean up the tags

There are currently several job-related tags that need people to go through and flag or vote to close questions that are no longer (or were never) on-topic:

- Jobs: [jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs), [job-market](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-market), [new-job](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-job), [job-definition](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-definition), [job-title](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-title), [job-hunting](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-hunting), [job-satisfaction](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-satisfaction), [job-distance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-distance), [job-retention](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-retention), [hpc-jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hpc-jobs), [scientific-computing-jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-computing-jobs)
- Career: [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career)
- Employment: [employment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment), [employer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employer), [employers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employers), [self-employment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-employment)
- Business: [business](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business), [business-process](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-process), [business-logic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-logic), [business-rules](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-rules), [business-analysis](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-analysis), [business-it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-it)
- Other: [interview](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview), [hiring](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiring), [project-management](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management), [teamwork](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teamwork)

Guidelines:

- When you're done cleaning up a tag, post an answer here that you've finished so others know to prioritize other tags.
- When in doubt about a question, create a new question here on meta instead of flagging so the community can decide if a question is a keeper.
- Start with the oldest questions first: our really old questions have a high likelihood of no longer meeting the site's guidelines, and are what are in most need of cleanup. We have plenty of time to deal with the newer stuff.

#### Step 2: Reorganize the survivors

We need to have a set of workable tags and tag synonyms, and any question that survived the purging needs to be edited to include those tags and improved in any way possible. [Aaronut's guidelines](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/tag-merge-discussion-jobs-career/1952#1952) are pretty good, so let's go with them:

- [career-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development) for questions that are about developing your career as a programmer.
- [job-market](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-market) for questions about the prospects of getting a *new* job.
- [job-satisfaction](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-satisfaction) for questions about work/life balance, creating better workspaces, etc.
- [job-advancement](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-advancement) and also [teamwork](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teamwork) for questions about excelling in one's current position.
- [project-management](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) and/or [employee-relations](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employee-relations) and/or [business](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business) for employer-focused questions.

Guidelines:

- If you have to deviate from the list above, **favor tag suffixes**: the system allows us to use wildcards in tag preferences, so [jobs-foo](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs-foo) is preferable to [foo-jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foo-jobs).
- **Spread out the organization.** Every time you edit a long-dead question to retag it, it bumps it back to the front page. Retagging 20+ questions at the same time kills the front-page usability for the rest of the visitors.
- **Start with the oldest questions first.** Our really old questions have a high likelihood of no longer meeting the site's guidelines, and are what are in most need of cleanup. We have plenty of time to deal with the newer stuff.
- **Request tag synonyms** by creating a question here on meta. This is especially important when a tag is organized out of existence (i.e. all the questions that had a tag have had that tag removed in favor of something else).
- **Don't bump questions you don't intend to see reopened.** This is going to be disruptive without bumping a ton of questions that don't belong here anyway. If you can save a question by substantially editing it, by all means do that, but if a question is just bad and already closed, at most just flag it for deletion.

#### Step 3: Burnination

Once all the good questions have been properly organized, we can go through the [normal clean-up process](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/programmers-se-summer-cleaning) of deleting old, off-topic stuff.

Comment: Note that I've unlinked [tag:career-advice] and [tag:career-development] so they can be used during the reorganization process.

Comment: Step 4: ??? Step 5: Profit.

Comment: So for step one, flag any off-topic posts with the listed tags?

Comment: @Glenn That's correct.

Comment: Love the [posse] tag. My work is piling up this week but I'll definitely do what I can. If I vote to close (as opposed to flagging), are mods/10kers going to help out by checking the close vote page, or am I better off just flagging them myself? (or voting *and* flagging?)

Comment: @Aaronaught I check the close vote page daily and review anything that's gotten at least two close votes.

Comment: Maybe to add to the guidelines: If you are bumping a question anyways, look if there are more things to edit in the question (and its answers).

Answer (score 3):

I've cleaned up [career-advice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-advice): any open questions were retagged and any closed questions were deleted.

I've also added new tag wikis for [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career), [jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs), [job-market](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-market), and [career-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development).

Finally, I've begun work on the gargantuan task of cleaning up [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career): starting from the newest questions and working backward, I'm cleaning up any non-closed question and adding the appropriate tags.

I'd welcome help in this, but we need to take care not to flood the home page with old questions. As a natural throttle, I'm not simply editing the tags, as nearly every question in [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) could use substantial improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Flagged about a dozen of questions under [interview](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview) as off topic, all of them are now closed. Started retagging some questions under [hiring](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiring) - oldest questions seemed to be on topic but with a variety of unhelpful tags, like [great-programmer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/great-programmer). I've spammed the frontpage with 5 old hiring questions, so it's probably time for a brake.

Answer (score 1):

- Flagged the one [scientific-computing-jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-computing-jobs) to be closed it's also the only [hpc-jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hpc-jobs) tagged question
- [job-retention](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-retention) was really about [employee-retention](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employee-retention) I've retagged but that's just a shuffle
- [job-distance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-distance) was on one open, and one closed question.  Deleted the tag from the open one because it already had [telecommute](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/telecommute) on it, because it seemed to be repeating itself and redundant too :-p

Answer (score 1):

- [business-it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-it) - 1 question flagged
- [job-title](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-title) - Several "What should I call my self". Top/Accepted
  answers didn't seem to offer much.
- [business-process](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-process) Question too specific to the person asking

Answer (score 0):

This is a good plan.

Unfortunately I'm having problems getting a stable connection to Stack Exchange at the moment so I won't be as active in this process as I perhaps should be.