# Blacklist [career] and [jobs]

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tag-blacklist

So pursuant to [the monumental task we have](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/posse-request-jobs-career-etc-tag-cleanup) to clean up the [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) and [jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs) tags, we've taken to putting the following notice in the tag wiki excerpts:

> Do not use this tag. Click "learn more" for better alternatives.

This, however, has not stopped people from adding more questions to the tags, which makes an already difficult task more difficult as more questions keep getting added.

I was under the assumption that blacklisting not only locked a tag, but blew it away from all existing tags, but after talking to people in Teachers' Lounge, I've found out that blacklisting and burninating are two separate actions: the former locks the tag, the latter kills the tag on all existing questions.

Just *locking* the [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) and [jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs) tags would help out a ton: it'd at least let us to freeze their usage while we stort out the 1500 questions already tagged with them.

So can we get these two tags blacklisted, but not burninated?

Comment: +1 for the puppy. How can you deny that face? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, we cannot simply "lock" the tags from future use without obliterating them. It causes ruckus and befuddlement as a person will see that not only is a tag quite voluminous, but it is also available on the tag suggestion list, and yet if they try to use it, they are barred.

I've [followed this up with a new question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2358/offering-solutions-to-the-career-and-jobs-tags) detailing what we *could* do to tackle this massive tag job.

---

I'm very much not a dog person, anyway.

Comment: First you decline the request, then you rub salt in the wound. A thousand ಠ_ಠ upon you!

Comment: Should have used tired kitten

Comment: Wow, when I hear a software developer say that they cannot satisfy a requirement, I wonder whether it is something that is really impossible, or if they just can't think of an solution off the top of their head? It's not like you were asked to solve N-Sat in polynomial time :-)