# How to detect questions inactive for longer than 6 months?

Tags: support, questions

You see **Excavator** badge to be given to somebody who has:

> Edited first post that was inactive for 6 months

This 6 month inactivity period has been mentioned in **Archaeologist** badge too.

The question is, how can I know that a question has been inactive for 6 months? Is there a list accessible of questions with this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can tell whether a question has been inactive for 6 months by looking at the stats in the sidebar:

[image: Question stats]

But these badges suck: you really shouldn't be looking for old questions to raise from the dead. If you happen to run into one, that's fine, but bumping a ton of long-dead questions to the front page just for the sake of the Archaeologist badge breaks the front page for other visitors.

If you want to help out with our cleanups and almost certainly get the Archaeologist badge along the way in due time, get involved in [the career and jobs tag cleanup](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/posse-request-jobs-career-etc-tag-cleanup).

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the link. +1 :)