# Is there a point to [software]?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have 121 questions tagged [software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software). I can't think of any valid (on topic) use for it.

Cleanup? Purge? Are there valid uses for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a junk tag, and it's a honeypot for junk questions and junk tags:

- [Closed questions: 21](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsoftware%5D+closed%3A1)
- [software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) + [software-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development): [9 questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software+software-development)
- [software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) + [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career): [5 questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software+career)
- [software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) + [development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development): [4 questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software+development)
- [software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) + [best-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices): [4 questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software+best-practices)
- [software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) + [experience](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience): [3 questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software+experience)
- [software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) + [developer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/developer): [3 questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software+developer)
- [software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) + [company](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/company): [2 questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software+company)

Kill it with fire. Please [observe normal tag cleanup rules](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/posse-request-jobs-career-etc-tag-cleanup).

Comment: Ok then, I removed the tag from 5 questions, will take a breather and continue at some point... Regarding closed ones, should I flag for deletion? And how does that work, ordinary mod attention flag with a delete this comment?

Comment: @YannisRizos I went ahead and deleted the low-to-mid scoring questions that weren't closed as exact duplicates: the others really need some community consensus before we can delete them. I've [opened a new question about dealing with them](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/2779/8).