# What can be done about the remaining closed questions in the "software" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, posse

As part of a cleanup of the [software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) tag [mentioned earlier on meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2773/is-there-a-point-to-software), we need to clean up the [closed questions found therein](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsoftware%5D+closed%3A1).

There's no point in shuffling around tags on questions that are off-topic or bad to begin with: if we can save these highly-upvoted questions, now's the time to do it.

#### 1.  Merge candidates

There are two questions that were closed as being exactly duplicates of earlier questions:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26076/what-are-some-handy-tools-in-windows-that-makes-programmers-life-easy → https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1913/what-are-the-must-have-development-tools-for-windows
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25181/what-are-the-symptoms-events-or-actions-of-a-software-death-cycle → [What are the warning signs of impending doom to watch out for on a project?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/what-are-the-warning-signs-of-impending-doom-to-watch-out-for-on-a-project)

Is there any reason why these questions should not be merged, effectively deleting the [software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) tagged versions?

If not, can these questions be improved so that they can be reopened? Otherwise, flag or vote for deletion so we can clean them up.

#### 2. The rest

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60303/what-are-nets-starlibs
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19408/what-are-must-have-tools-for-web-development
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40477/what-is-the-worst-software-bug-in-history
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26076/what-are-some-handy-tools-in-windows-that-makes-programmers-life-easy
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5168/whats-the-biggest-software-security-vulnerabilty-youve-personally-discovered

Can these questions be saved by a heroic edit and community pruning?

If any of these questions can be saved, please be bold and do so: flag bad answers for deletion, combine piecemeal answers into a single canonical one, rewrite the question, flag for reopening.

Otherwise, the end game for these questions is deletion; so if there's something about these questions that necessitate them being here, let's whip them into shape.

Comment: What are the guidelines for merging small answers into a single all-encompassing answer? Should I just edit an existing answer and go from there?

Comment: @GlennNelson Yep, edit an existing answer and flag the now-obsolete answer for deletion. A canonical answer will eventually convert to community wiki, but you can also flag the answer you're making canonical so we can speed that process along.

Comment: @YannisRizos Voting to close and flagging is fine, but if there's a reasonable number of them, consider posting the list here on meta to get other eyes on them.

Comment: @MarkTrapp I'm almost done cleaning up the tag, all that remains is the list in my answer. Give it a look when you'll have some time...

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox [Check out my answer](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/2885/8) for how we'll handle them. If people aren't bothering to save them, they're on their way to deletion.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Cool, thanks. I'll check back at some point. Time to resume cleaning up career then...

Answer (score 3):

[software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) questions that should probably be closed:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57653/registering-in-the-ios-developer-program-as-a-minor
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54487/whats-the-best-way-of-marketing-to-programmers
- [Which skills would you expect and appreciate in a Junior Software Engineer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48100/which-skills-would-you-expect-and-appreciate-in-a-junior-software-engineer)
- [Recommendations for a web-based help system](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47963/recommendations-for-a-web-based-help-system)
- [How do big companies of software developers check for bugs in their programs?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46965/how-do-big-companies-of-software-developers-check-for-bugs-in-thier-programs)
- [How can software be protected from piracy?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46434/why-is-it-that-software-is-still-easily-pirated-today)
- [Is there a source for user opinions on commercial enterprise software?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81919/is-there-a-source-for-user-opinions-on-commercial-enterprise-software)
- [What should I know before starting a software company?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72967/i-want-to-create-a-software-company-what-are-the-basic-things-that-i-should-kno)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63602/entry-into-software-field-after-7-years-gap
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40134/information-on-small-business-software-development
- [What are the different methods of dividing and organizing work among project team members?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/67054/work-division-horizontal-vs-vertical)
- [Do you use Mathematica during the software development process?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40593/do-you-use-mathematica-during-the-software-development-process)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20476/why-is-it-so-hard-to-get-people-to-pay-for-software
- [Where do I begin when dealing with my first corporate client?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43752/where-do-i-begin-when-dealing-with-my-first-corporate-client)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17434/the-useful-tools-for-windows-device-driver-developers
- [What tools can be used to facilitate code reviews after commits?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39122/post-commit-code-review-tools)
- [How to implement software for my vehicle](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/41678/how-to-implement-software-for-my-vehicle)

I'll keep updating the list as I go through the tag, all of the above got my close vote for one reason or the other. Everyone please review and:

1. Try to salvage, or
2. Flag / Vote to close

Please do not vote to migrate, most of the questions are really old and there is no point in migrating them on StackOverflow, or anywhere else.

---

**Done.**

I've gone through each and every one of the questions. The only open ones still tagged [software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) are the ones in this list. They all got *my* close vote, but of course I'm not assuming they will be closed.

Moderators (and everyone, really), please review the list.

Comment: Just to note: I'm noticing a lot of old questions getting votes to migrate to Stack Overflow: if a question is dead, migrating it now is futile at best. Just vote to close as off-topic.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Reverse crap migration! Let the games begin...

Comment: I just finished going through the list. I cleaned up some posts, tags, and voted to close as I felt was appropriate. /cc @MarkTrapp

Comment: @ThomasOwens Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After 2.5 weeks of no objections or attempts to salvage the questions, I went ahead and did the following:

#### Merged

- [What are some handy tools in Windows that makes programmers life easy?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26076/what-are-some-handy-tools-in-windows-that-makes-programmers-life-easy) → [What are the must have development tools for Windows](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1913/what-are-the-must-have-development-tools-for-windows)
- [What are the symptoms, events or actions of a software death cycle?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25181/what-are-the-symptoms-events-or-actions-of-a-software-death-cycle) → [What are the warning signs of impending doom to watch out for on a project?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/what-are-the-warning-signs-of-impending-doom-to-watch-out-for-on-a-project)

#### Deleted

- [What are .NET's #starlibs?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60303/what-are-nets-starlibs)
- [What are must have tools for web development?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19408/what-are-must-have-tools-for-web-development)
- [What is the worst software bug in history?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40477/what-is-the-worst-software-bug-in-history)
- [What are some handy tools in Windows that makes programmers life easy?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26076/what-are-some-handy-tools-in-windows-that-makes-programmers-life-easy)
- [What's the biggest software security vulnerabilty you've personally discovered?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5168/whats-the-biggest-software-security-vulnerabilty-youve-personally-discovered)

The next step is to work through [Yannis's list of close candidates](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2813/8): we will be closing questions that are off-topic, not constructive, or too localized as written. After a month, they will be deleted. So now's the time to save any questions there with heroic edits.