# Burninate the [work] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

There's a [work](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work) tag. Looks like it was missed in the [Posse request: jobs/career/etc. tag cleanup](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/posse-request-jobs-career-etc-tag-cleanup)

Burninate/cleanup? Seems like a likely target of off topic questions, so I'd recommend going through them and removing the tag as they're closed/edited. There's <del>80</del>   **13**. As a mod from Workplace I can already tell you The Workplace won't be accepting any old questions with the tag.

Comment: Just to reiterate what Ben says. Edit the question if you think it can be salvaged, vote to close or flag if you think it can't.

Comment: Working on burninating them now. Will be editing/flagging for closure on ones that aren't already closed - where neccessary :)

Answer (score 5):

I have gone through and re-tagged the closed questions and put more appropriate tags where possible. I have also re-tagged a few of the questions that didn't really need improvement.

Will work on looking at the other questions in the list and editing/tagging/flagging where appropriate, and try not to spam the home page (or the review queue as my rep here is too low to edit).

**Edit**: We're down to 35 now, still slowly working on it. Having troubles deciding whether some should be open or not, I'll seek clarification in chat. I've found a few where they are linked to questions that have been closed as duplicates of the question in context - so I just removed the tags on those ones.

**Edit edit**: All burned now.. I see 0 questions under the work tag. Yay

Answer (score 2):

All questions have been retagged or destroyed.

Comment: Hm? I see 10 questions left: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work

Comment: I see 0, I don't have mod vision though.

Comment: No mod vision involved, I still see open / non deleted questions tagged [work] (and others do as well, there have been a couple of flags on them since your previous comment).

Comment: I see them. I'll chalk it up to tired + head full of DIP and Algorithms homework.