# Improperly prompting for career development tags in new questions

Tags: bug, status-completed

In the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) it plainly states that career advice questions are not appropriate.  Yet when a new question is being asked you are prompted to input a tag, including the [career-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development).  Perhaps we shouldn't prompt users to input this tag if it is not appropriate for the site.

---

[image: A screenshot showing improper tag prompt]

Comment: That's a very good point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As ChrisF has said, the example tags are randomly pulled from the top 30 tags on the site, but they're usage counts from all **undeleted** questions - closed questions are still included!

I've checked in a change that excludes closed questions from these usage counts.  While it won't remove [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) from the list, it will push [career-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development) out of the top 30.

Comment: Excellent move. I assume that this applies to all sites.

Comment: Yes, this affects all sites.

Answer (score 7):

These suggestions come from the existing tag base. It's certainly not based on the tags I've asked questions in previously or answered questions, and it's not the [most popular tags](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags). If I ask a question I get a different set:

[image]

so there is be a random element in there - in fact the three example tags are chosen randomly from the top thirty tags on the site. If you notice mine even suggests the [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) tag - even worse! - these tags persist for me when I open the Ask Question page again, so there is an element of caching in there as well.

Once the bad tags are removed from all questions ([hint, hint](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3088/31260)) then they shouldn't appear in the list again, so get retagging.

One of the developers will see this question and be able to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Spot on answer.