# Is there any correlation with the number of tags used and the quality of a question?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do more tags mean a better question? a worse question? Is this even a relevant metric? I feel like more tags are indicative of an unfocused question or a question that is desperate for answers. Any data to support or refute this assertion?

Comment: For anyone with good skills with the data explorer, some interesting data would be: questions open/closed with each number of tags, number of tags vs views, number of tags vs votes, number of tags vs answers.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it indicates a better/worse question, although it might indicate a newer user.

Before I understood how SE worked, I used to always use 5 tags because I thought it meant I would get more views. I'd actually spend extra time trying to figure out a 4th or 5th tag, even if one wasn't actually needed.

Now I understand how SE works better, and only use more tags if the question warrents more tags. And it turns out, most questions I ask don't need more than 2, maybe 3, tags.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a relevant metric, quantitative metrics rarely are.

Empirically, questions that have five tags (the upper limit) tend to be better quality wise from questions that have a single or two tags, because the OP put a little bit more effort in categorizing the question. Four/five good tags is a hint that the OP is familiar with the site, but just a hint, the question itself may be crappy.

Then again, it's not extremely rare to see questions (good and bad) with three or four useless tags (think: [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)). I don't remember seeing a question with five useless tags, let's hope the [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career)[career-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development)[software-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development)[software-engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-engineering)[best-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices) beast remains a mythical one.

We seem to have a bigger problem with tagging than other sites, at least the sites I frequent. If you take a look at [stci](/questions/tagged/stci), [tags](/questions/tagged/tags), [tag-blacklist](/questions/tagged/tag-blacklist) and [tag-merge](/questions/tagged/tag-merge) questions you'll get a better idea of the various tagging issues we've had (and in some cases continue to have). The first [Structured Tag Cleanup](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3087/structured-tag-cleanup-call-for-proposals-1) starts tomorrow, hopefully we will get rid of some of the most troublesome tags.

Now, let's see how we can retag this question, because [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) alone doesn't say much...

---

**Interesting SEDE queries**

- [How many tags per question](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/61441/how-many-tags-per-question)
- [Average tag count per question](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/61442/average-tag-count-per-question)
- [How many tags per question for top questions?](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/59225/)
- [Close count per tag with close rate >= 10%](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/52897/close-count-per-tag-with-close-rate-10) (irrelevant but still interesting!)