# Remove CW conversion at 30 answers

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, community-wiki

Since most questions here can have an unlimited number of answers, I think the automatic conversion to CW when a question receives 30 answers should be removed.

See also: [Purpose of Community Wiki](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/purpose-of-community-wiki)

Comment: +1.  Besides, that's not StackOverflow, people are loosing reputation for otherwise good questions.

Comment: +1, I agree with this!

Answer (score 20):

I still fail to see any reason why any post should be CW here. We definitely need to do away with the automatic conversion, and I'm not even sure we need a flag.

Comment: The only reason I see is for posts that would benefit from collaboration.

Comment: @TomWij:  Yes, and since this is more of an opinion than a fact site, collaboration is less useful.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with this, maybe there should instead be a flag reason for a question to be made a community wiki...

Answer (score 2):

I would love to be able to upvote this question, but the automatic CW conversion has actually kept me below the 15 reputation needed to vote. In a technical forum with specific answers, it helps to keep the answer count down, but in a more discussion oriented forum, where the answers are often opinions, it actually ends up penalizing people for participating.

Comment: Don't you have an SO account? Didn't you link it to this one?

Answer (score 1):

I think CW makes sense for some questions.

For example, the "[What features would you like to have in PHP?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27564/what-features-would-you-like-to-have-in-php)" question is well-suited for this: People can feel free to both submit their ideas *and* to down vote ideas they disfavor. Because votes don't affect reps you can see where the consensus is: what is popular, what is controversial (*provided you have the ability view vote counts*) and what is plain unpopular.

Without CW, there would be less freedom for suggesting ideas. Meta works similarly in this regard.