# Why isn't my reputation increasing?

Tags: support, reputation

I have [an answer with 10 up-votes](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/#1993) on programmers.stackexchange.com, but my reputation is still stuck at 101 (for linking my accounts across other Stack* sites).  Shouldn't my reputation be increasing for each up-vote I get?

Comment: Cool, an Ars Technica columnist... Welcome to Programmers! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a ["Community Wiki"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) answer (one which doesn't have a permanent "owner", can be edited by more users, and doesn't grant reputation to anyone) - this status is forced for answers to questions with more than 30 answers. On the other sites, this is done to try and reduce the motivation for posting duplicate answers on open-ended questions...

For this site, [there's some discussion as to whether it's a useful behavior](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145/remove-cw-conversion-at-30-answers).

Comment: Doh!  Forgot about the community wiki thing.  I knew it had to be something obvious…

Comment: That seems pretty poor. Why should someone be penalised for asking/answering a good question, just because lots of other people wade in? This is far more likely to happen here than on SO

Comment: @adolf: please follow the link at the end of this answer. AFAIK, this *can* be adjusted on a per-site basis, but it requires administrator/developer intervention.