# Why Isn't My Reputation Updating?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, status-bydesign, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't my reputation increasing?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/why-isnt-my-reputation-increasing)

I received several upvotes between 10/21 and 10/24 but my reputation screen doesn't show them and they weren't and aren't counted toward my rep.  By my calculations, I'm about 20 rep behind where I should be.

I know of [at least 2 upvotes](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6847/whats-your-favorite-programming-language/12424#12424) that did not cause a change in my rep.  As you can see, both between 10/21 and 10/24.

I know 20 rep is no big deal, but if this is a problem it should be pointed out.  As you can see, my [stats](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/4971?tab=stats) tab shows 3 answers with upvotes but my [rep](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/4971?tab=reputationhistory) tab only shows two.

Excerpt from my rep screen:

```
-- 2010-10-19 rep +58   = 87        
 1     12870 (15)
 1     11836 (2)
-- 2010-10-21 rep +17   = 104       
-- 2010-10-24 rep 0     = 104       
 2     12870 (10)
-- 2010-10-25 rep +10   = 114 `
```

I already made a question about this but [it disappeared](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/476/question-i-asked-dissappeared).

Comment: See the accepted answer to the linked question.

Comment: Oh, CW!  I knew I missed something....