# How to make my question community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Purpose of Community Wiki](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/purpose-of-community-wiki)

I just posted [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20363/what-is-the-most-inspiring-speech-from-a-developer-you-ever-watched) question.

I saw no options to make it community wiki. I remember that option. Why I don't see it?

Answer (score 3):

See [What can we do to make Community Wiki better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192) on Meta.SO. So you can request it for moderators, but I just convert to CW if the question requires CW status. If you want it, please explain why.