# What's the point of 'Unanswered' link?

Tags: discussion, support

We have a link at the top of each page titled 'Unanswered'. Clicking it yields a list of questions and how many answers they have. Last time I clicked it, all questions listed had at least 2 answers.

So, it's behaving like "All questions without an accepted answer" - but there's an [amount](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/why-would-anyone-accept-an-answer) of [discussion](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/should-we-worry-about-accept-rate) around the subjective nature of Programmers' questions meaning that the accepted answer isn't a useful concept - there are plenty of equally-valid answers to many of the questions here.

Even for Stack Overflow, isn't it just highlighting that the questioner hasn't accepted an answer yet, even though there's no (technical) forcing function to comply them to do so? On Programmers, this is largely irrelevant.

So.. what's the point of the 'Unanswered' link..? Is it still useful?

Answer (score 6):

[Dori is right](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/607/whats-the-point-of-unanswered-link/626#626). It's actually explained on the Unanswered page, but for some reason people tend to miss it:

[image: Screenshot of the Unanswered tab]

Comment: LOL. We bypass most the important explanatory texts here. SE developers took care to explain in a simple way but we users bypass it offhandedly. Users are always users!