# Can the accept rate be removed?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, removal, accept-rate

The "accept rate" feature seems useless to me and only leads into frustration for those asking questions.

[See this question.](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/should-we-worry-about-accept-rate) (And no, it's not a duplicate as that question isn't a feature request...)

**Related**: [Alternative solution that can replace accept rate](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108/should-the-point-distribution-system-be-changed-to-encourage-discussion-not-answ/192#192) if we still want to allow "agreement" of answers.

Comment: An explanation of the accept rate needs to be explained to everyone. People still think its necessary to have a 100% accept rate

Comment: I don't think that explaining why it is useless is the right solution, and a lot of people don't read everything...

Comment: Accept rate is not displayed any more, for details see: [Let's stop displaying a user's accept rate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate)

Answer (score 10):

Accept Rate is a great concept for the completely non-subjective sites like Stack Overflow, but probably doesn't work as well for a more subjective site like Programmers.

Answer (score 4):

I agree.  People judge otherwise useful answers according to someones "Accept Rate".

Answer (score -1):

It's there, it's sort of interesting, it may or may not be probative.

We're *coders* for goodness sake, can't we all accept that and refrain from overanalyzing?