# Accept rate not hidden? I thought we already discussed this

Tags: discussion, design, accept-rate

A long time ago we discussed the importance of the accept rate. Here are some examples:

- [Should we worry about accept rate?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/should-we-worry-about-accept-rate) - 16 votes on question, 25 votes + accepted answer on request to remove + 24 combined votes on other answers
- [Can the accept rate be removed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/495/can-the-accept-rate-be-removed) - 16 votes on question + 10 combined votes on answers
- [Why would anyone accept an answer?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/why-would-anyone-accept-an-answer) - Some backbround on why this is an issue

I was a bit disappointed when the new site design didn't hide the accept rates. The general consensus when those questions were asked was that we can't change anything now since were in beta but once we get out of beta, this will change. Which hasn't.

Is this something that can be done?

Answer (score 4):

The consensus, if you could call it that, on removing the accept rate was mostly achieved before [Great Redisiplining](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/the-six-subjective-question-guidelines-enforcement-notice). People can and should be accepting answers: the acceptance criteria on all Stack Exchange sites is "this answer helped me, personally, the most."

#### Edit

To clarify, the re-disiplining of Programmers.SE set guidelines that discourage people from asking questions they don't actually need the answers to (i.e. so-called "pointless water cooler nonsense"). With that, the [standard criteria for accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) applies to all questions on Programmers.SE like it does on the rest of the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: The disciplining never mentioned anything about accept rate. And since nobody has been really doing it, when did this shift occur then? Once a data dump comes out it will be interesting to see how many accepted questions there is

Comment: @TheLQ: Anyway it's implied. Here, accept rate is not a big issue but still useful.

Comment: I don't see any connection between "The Great Redisciplining" and accept rate, nor do I remember any discussion about the "new consensus" (apologies if I just haven't seen that discussion).  Subjective questions are still subjective, even if they meet all six of the guidelines.

Comment: @Robert @TheLQ The re-disiplining of Programmers.SE set guidelines that discourage people asking questions they don't actually need the answers to (i.e. so-called "pointless water cooler nonsense"). With that, the [standard criteria for accepting answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) applies to all questions on Programmers.SE like it does on the rest of the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable argument.  Changed -1 to +1.